# FactoryGirl define attribute by calling method on another factory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, factory-bot

Here is an example from the FactoryGirl [documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/wiki/Usage):

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :post do
    name "Post name"
    user
  end
end
```

In this example, `user` is invoking another factory. What I would like to do is effectively call `user.id`, but to set it as the definition of an attribute. Here's a stripped-down example:

```
**models/job.rb**
  ...
  belongs_to :assignee, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :user
  ...
  attr_accessible :assignee_id, :user_id
  ...
end


**factories/jobs.rb**
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :job do
    assignee_id user.id      #what I would like to do, but triggers "undefined method 'id'" error
    user_id user.id          #user_id is an attribute of the model and is the job assignor
 end
```

I've tried to incorporate the part of the documentation that discusses aliases, but with no luck:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user, :aliases => [:assignee] do
  ....
```

I feel like (hope?) I'm close here, but any insight is appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT:  This code gets my specs running!

```
**factories/jobs.rb**

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :job do
    before(:create) do |job|
      user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      job.assignee = user
      job.user  = user
    end

  association :assignee, factory: :user
  association :user, factory: :user
  sequence(:user_id) { |n| n }
  sequence(:assignee_id) { |n| n }
  ...
end
```

And it passes my `it { should be_valid }` spec, so it seems that the factory is fine, though I think I have some refactoring in the spec itself when I'm calling `FactoryGirl.create`.

The code above incorporates the suggestions from mguymon. Thanks!

FINAL UPDATE

After going back and re-reading [Hartl's discussion on model associations](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/user-microposts#sec-user_micropost_associations), I was able to put this matter to rest. What I have above was techincally valid, but didn't actually pass the attributes in properly when i built or created jobs in my spec. Here's what I should have had:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :job do
    association :assignee, factory: :user
    user
  end
end
```

My problem also stemmed from how I was creating factories in my spec, so here's how I should have been doing it (but wasn't...sigh):

```
    let(:user) { create(:user) }
    before { @job = create(:job, user: @user) }
```

It seems that I don't explicitly have to have `association :user` in my factory, nor do I need the `before` block from above.

As an aside, I also learned that I can debug by including `puts @job` within an `expect` statement, or call `@job.assignee_id` to make sure that the attributes are being loaded properly. When that particular spec is run, the `puts` statement will output right by the `F` or `.` from the spec.

Comment: sorry, but can you show the exception stack trace? thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For the latest version of FactoryGirl, use `association` to map to other ActiveRecord Models:

```
factory :job do
  # ...
  association :assignee, factory: :user
end
```

This is straight from [the docs](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md).

---

From the error you posted, it is stating you are trying to get the `user.id` but `user` is not an ActiveRecord instance but a proxy from FactoryGirl. You will not get this error if you are using the `association` method. If you need to directly access a model, you have to manually build it first. You can do this by passing a *block* in your factory:

```
factory :job do
    assignee_id { FactoryGirl.create(:user).id }
end
```

It looks like you are trying to associate the same model twice, for this you can use `before_create` callback to create a User model and assign to `user` and `assignee`:

```
factory :job do

  before(:create) do |job|
      user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      job.assignee = user
      job.user = user
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and link. Even with the association (which I'm sure is need), I'm still getting an "undefined method 'id'" error.

Comment: Your edit did the trick. Now that my specs finally run, I need to go through and fix some troublesome failures caused by duplicate users...

Comment: It turns out I didn't need `before(:create), nor did I need to create a user from the Factory. Though my factory was testing as valid, it wasn't properly loading the attributes into the jobs I was creating or building in my specs (I verified this by using puts @job within specs). I've added the correct code (or, at least a better version...maybe there is a 'more correct' version) to my question, but I'm leaving your answer as the checked answer since I explicitly needed to associate the assignee with the user and wouldn't of got that without your help.